# How do I flatten a big color target for shooting

Tags: colorchecker

I just brought a new color target but upon a week it started to curl up so I couldn't shoot it with even lighting. The target is about 16 x 12 inch. I have asked the seller for help and he said to glue it to a harder base, but I'm having a hard time to come up with a base of this size. What are the good options to flatten it?

[image]

Comment: I do not think this is related to photography.

Comment: A material that is perfectly flat, doesn't bend and is easily available in these sizes is glass. Just a bit on the heavy or fragile side (but tempered glass for table tops is pretty tough).

Answer (score 0):

Any craft shop that does framing, like a Michaels, will generally have matte board as well as the tools to cut it and adhesive for wet mounting or photo corners for something less permanent.

Additionally dollar stores (Dollar Tree in particular) tend to carry foam core for use in school presentations.

Comment: I'd consider plywood or particleboard. Some home improvement stores will even cut to size for you.

Comment: I checked out the mat boards, they look pretty good, light weight and has good thickness. My target board thickness is 2.16 mm, what is the optimal thickness of the base board to hold straight the target board? Do I need thickness greater that 2.16 mm or do I need one that doubles it?

Comment: No. Please. Plywood is too much and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I would NOT make a permanent "solution". You can regret it.

Get a fibracel (the boards that are made from compressed cardboard, the ones with holes are used in workshops to hang tools)

Cut it to the exact size, and clamp it when you need it with some binder paperclips. There are several thicknesses, so you can have some small ones that perfectly fit.

I am not sure of the exact names in English. Here are some images.

[image]

With some creativity, you can cover or wrap it in a nice fabric and use it to actually protect the color target **(B)**.

[image]You can even make a "V" card with two, and then they will be a stand for it **C**.

Comment: I think those are called hardboard, the Staples clipboard in my photo is a hardboard. Yup it is smooth, hard and flat. I just looked it up and Blick has the same size for $4. The problem though is the clippers, their springs look way too strong, they are going to leave dents in my target board.

Comment: Cut 2 additional strips of that material and use it to sandwich and protect the card. They will help the flattening.

Comment: Thanks, I picked up some foam and a binder clip in my house along with my clipboard and tested it. It works, the target board was flatten with no dents. Now I'll just need to look for some weaker and longer clips as the binder clip is way too strong.

Comment: Try some simple wire clips.

Comment: Update, I brought the larger clips and clipped the chart to a hardboard on 3 sides. Examining the sides shows that the they were flatten. However, a shot of the target shows that the white patch in the middle is still 5% brighter than the white patches on the sides no matter how I adjusted my flashes' position. So I think there's still a warp in the middle even though all the sides has been flattened. Now how do I flatten the middle? Do I have any other non permanent options than double sided tape?